# How to crop face from landmarks in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop

I have the locations of outer landmark points, something like this:

[image]

And now I want to "close" this contour from the outer chin and eyebrows and mask everything out to zero, so I want to obtain something like this :

[image]

So I guess I have 2 things to do :

1. Calculate the "outer" polygon, and create a mask out of it
2. Determine the inner region, multiply with binary mask, and crop from the bounding box

I'm not sure how to do either of them. Are there easy, MATLAB-specific ways for this? Or an example?

Thanks for any help!

### Edit

I found `roipoly` from this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1799-regarding-cropping-a-polygon-out-of-an-image), but it asks the user to give the polygon I guess. Can I compute it automatically?

### Edit 2

Yes I can, simply with `BW = roipoly(img, c,r); img2 = img.*uint8(BW);`
However, the problem still remains which landmarks to use for the contours. I can assign them rule based, but what if I want to select the "outer" landmarks automatically?

So I guess now the question is transformed into:

Given N points on 2D plane, how do I select the subset (i.e. the outer surface) that creates a polygon that covers all of the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boundary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) and [`poly2mask`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) as follows. I manually marked several points as you did not provide your face coordinates.

```
clc; clear all;

img = imread('FAm1z.jpg');
figure; imshow(img);

[x,y] = ginput(50);

k = boundary(x,y,0);
hold on;
plot(x,y,'ro');
plot(x(k),y(k));

mask = poly2mask(x(k), y(k), size(img,1), size(img,2));
mask(:,:,2) = mask;
mask(:,:,3) = mask(:,:,1);

roi = img;
roi(mask == 0) = 0;

figure; imshow(roi);
```

Output images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! IIUC, your code also does the selection of outer landmarks, so you put the nose and mouth, but it succesfully ignored them, right? If so, this is just what I want. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, that is the beauty of Matlab boundary. You can actually change the last parameter between [0, 1] to specify the shrink factor. 0 gives you the convex hull.